# Magento 2.2.5: Explain about Position in "Catalog_Category_Product"

Tags: magento2, catalog

I'm looking for an explaination about column `"Position"` in table `"Catalog_Category_Product"`.
I dont understand what is 0 and 1 in that column, and what does it for?
Thanks for reading. Have a good day :)

EDIT 1:

Maybe i'm not clear enough when asking the question, so...

I'm trying to do "banner_slider" follow the structure of "catalog_category_product"

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AssignProducts.php

So in that code, i debug with xdebug phpstorm and realize that position="1" show in "yes", but in the database it have position="0" as well. I dont know what it does .. That's what i'm wondering
Here is what i debug:

```
public function getProductsJson()
{
    $products = $this->getCategory()->getProductsPosition();
    if (!empty($products)) {
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($products);
    }
    return '{}';
}
```

[image]

[image]

After running that code, they render throught this in "getProductsJson()" function:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\templates\catalog\category\edit\assign_products.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AssignProducts $block */

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product $blockGrid */
$blockGrid = $block->getBlockGrid();
$gridJsObjectName = $blockGrid->getJsObjectName();
?>
<?= $block->getGridHtml() ?>
<input type="hidden" name="category_products" id="in_category_products" data-form-part="category_form" value="" />
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Catalog/catalog/category/assign-products": {
                "selectedProducts": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductsJson() ?>,
                "gridJsObjectName": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '"' . $gridJsObjectName . '"' ?: '{}' ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- @todo remove when "UI components" will support such initialization -->
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>
```

Comment: Accept answer which is really useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Category products display based on set position. You can check product position  in admin >> Catalog >> Categories >> Select any category >> Product In Category.

You can check below reference screenshots, admin and front.

Admin : [image]

Front : [image]

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Hmm .. okay, so i already know this, i'm trying to do "banner_slider" follow this structure of "category_product" (which you are showing to me). So in that code, i debug with xdebug phpstorm and realize that position="1" show in "yes", but in the database it have position="0" as well. I dont know what it does .. that what i'm wondering.

Comment: I've edited the post, please check :)

Answer (score 2):

You can sort products inside a category. Just go the backend, edit a category's product list - you will find the field "position" there; insert any number, not only "0" and "1" are possible.

Position is also the default sorting for categories in Magento. You can change that in the backend in Shops > Configuration > Catalog.

This is an answer that can easily be solved by googling, so please do this next time before you ask something here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Hmm .. okay, so i already know this, i'm trying to do "banner_slider" follow this structure of "category_product" (which you are showing to me). So in that code, i debug with xdebug phpstorm and realize that position="1" show in "yes", but in the database it have position="0" as well. I dont know what it does .. that what i'm wondering.

Comment: I've edited the post, please check :)